# How to get SQL code to send error message when writing in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have code that uploads an excel spreadsheet per the user and then once uploaded, I have it updating one of the colummns in SQL based on another SQL Table. I'd like to verify the data in the Excel Spreadsheet matches one of the options to update from in the SQL table. What's the easiest way? I.e. Can I add a SQL statement to give me an error message on the website if a NULL value is returned or do I have to write a complex IF statement in C#? Here's what I have so far (see SQL Statement):

```
try
    {

        FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
        if (TextBox.Text != "")
        sheetname = TextBox.Text;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;  //check sheet name
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
        MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetname + "$]", MyConnection);
        //MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [July Noms$]", MyConnection);
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
        DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
        SqlConnection curConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=1tc-Techcomm2;Initial Catalog=EventRegistration;Integrated Security=True");
        curConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand curCommand;
        SqlParameter param;
        string str;

        for (int i = 0; i < DtSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (DtSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] == DBNull.Value)
                continue;
            curCommand = curConnection.CreateCommand();
            curCommand.CommandText = @"Insert into TestSP (SessionHead_EventId, SessionHead_Title, SessionHead_TypeId, SessionHead_Description, SessionHead_Status, SessionHead_Presenter, SessionHead_Champion, SessionHead_AnnounceDate, SessionHead_Objectives, SessionHead_LaunchDate, SessionHead_Notes, SessionHead_Schedule, SessionHead_SpecialNeeds, SessionHead_Equipment, SessionHead_CDA) Values (@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,@m,@n,@o)";
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
            {
                param = new SqlParameter();
                str = "@";
                str += (char)('a' + j);
                param.ParameterName = str;
                param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                param.Value = DtSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j];
                curCommand.Parameters.Add(param);

            }
            Label1.Text = "THE EXCEL DATE HAS SUCCESSFULLY BEEN SENT TO THE DATABASE";
            curCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            curCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE TestSP SET SessionHead_TypeId = ( SELECT SessionType.SessionType_Id FROM SessionType WHERE SessionType.SessionType_Title = TestSP.SessionHead_TypeId) WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT SessionType.SessionType_Id FROM SessionType WHERE SessionType.SessionType_Title = TestSP.SessionHead_TypeId)"; 
//****Can I add a statement here stating that if a NULL value is returned, to give me an error message on the website?****

        curCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }


        MyConnection.Close();
        curConnection.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        Label2.Text = ex.Message; 

    }


}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, `ExecuteNonQuery` returns an integer, so you can just check its return value against 0. Unless you're not explaining it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use stored procedures to return an sql error message.

Answer (score 0):

catch of `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` will give you error message if query is false.
Also `ExecuteNonQuery` will give you integer for affected rows. So, `0` if there are no affected row and `-1` if there are something wrong such as rollback.